# C#: Renaming files on the result of `Directory.EnumerateFiles` causes infinite loop

Tags: c#, file-rename, enumerator

I have a folder contains a lot of files(>100000),
and I want to write some code to perform a batch renaming.
I use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` rather than `Directory.GetFiles` since the former does not allocate the space for all the files name so I don't need to be worried about the memory.
Here is the code:

```cs
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\many_files");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // Use`File.Move` to do the renaming stuff
}
```

However I encountered an infinite loop.
That's because `EnumerateFiles` is executing along with the renaming action. So after renaming a file, the file might be reordered to the end of the "enumeration list" and `EnumerateFiles` will return it again.

So Is there a solution? Or I have to use the `GetFiles` which may cause OOM.

Comment: Can you store them all in another list first and then process that list when renaming? Steer clear of changing objects in a for loop, that’s my advice.

Comment: @Skin That would be same to be using `GetFiles` I think.

Comment: if you really cant fit all file names is a memory them write them all out to a text file, then read the text file to drive the rename loop, you can enumerate the lines in the file so it doesnt all get read at once

Comment: Can't you tell which file has already been renamed?

Comment: Sort by directory date added ascending -> and then do a batch processing(per 100), THis way the newest files are always at the end of enumeration, and you'll know where you are

Comment: Since you are renaming the files and if you got some format while renaming, then you know which files to skip when you enumerate.

Comment: @WAKU - "That would be same to be using GetFiles I think." - No, it would not. You're renaming the files, not changing the list.

Comment: @Enigmativity I mean the memory issue would be the same as `GetFiles`

Comment: @ashwathmabiyan It's hard to say. For example I have 100 files named `1.txt`, `2.txt` ... `100.txt`, and the renaming requirement is "plus 1" to the file name, the result should be `2.txt`, `3.txt` and `101.txt`, though it's a rare scenario, I cannot easily know if the file has been renamed.

Comment: If you have so many files to process, why not use some temporary storage to track progress and even restart the process if it's interrupted? This could be a simple text file or something more advanced like an SQLite database

Comment: @WAKU - If you're doing that kind of rename (i.e. `{n}.txt` -> `{n+1}.txt`) then you're going to need to start from the end and work backwards to avoid duplicate names or rename to intermediate names. Or maybe do some sort of complicated graph traversal to avoid duplicates. You're in a much bigger world of pain now.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes I know the example is more complicated, I take it just want to say it's not always easy to know if the file is renamed.

Comment: @WAKU - It's easy to know if it is renamed. It's hard to know if it can be safely renamed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to load all the filePaths in memory and rename them.

Since you're worried about memory, You can do this:
Provided there wouldn't be any additions to the directory during this process.

```
static void Rename(string path, int batchSize = 5)
{
    var queryable = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).AsQueryable(); //Queryable For Getting Files

    var totalFiles = queryable.Count(); //Get Total File Count in Path

    int count = 0;//counter

    while (count <= totalFiles)
    {
        var filesToProcess = queryable
                            .Where(f => !Path.GetFileName(f).StartsWith("reviewed_")) //Get Files Without this prefix
                            .Skip(count)
                            .Take(batchSize)
                            .ToList();//Get Batch To Process

        foreach (var file in filesToProcess)
        {
            //Do Renaming Stuff
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }

        count += batchSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use `Regex.Replace(file, "^", "reviewed_")` to add prefix to the file name, the code seems rename some files repeatly.

Comment: Check updated answer, you can add a check with a where clause while getting files

Comment: `AsQueryable` isn't needed. These operations will enumerate all the files multiple times. `Count()` *has* to enumerate all files to provide a count. The subsequent batch operations will enumerable the files all over again. Each subsequent iteration will be even slower as `Skip` will have to enumerate more and more files

Comment: Finally, renaming will still be a problem. A renamed file can still appear later on, leading to an infinite loop

Comment: Classic speed vs memory. Check the poster's requirements, he's too worried about memory and doesn't mind a slower algo.  As for renamed files reapearing, We check for that with the "reviewed_" check